# Trying to run a headless executable command through Powershell that works on cmd line

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run an executable through powershell to run headless, to install a program onto a VM/LocalHost machine. I can get the wizard to open, but for whatever reason I cannot get it to run headless. Here is the cmd line that I run that works:

> ```
> start /WAIT setup.exe /clone_wait /S /v" /qn"
> ```

This is my attempts in powershell

> ```
> Start-Process .\setup.exe /S -Wait -PassThru
> ```

> ```
> Start-Process .\setup.exe /S /v /qn -Wait -PassThru
> ```

> ```
> Start-Process setup.exe -ArgumentList '/clone_wait /S /v /qn' -Wait
> ```

In the cmd line instance the application installs without issue - in the powershell instance the wizard opens and is on the first "Next" prompt. Any help would be appreciated!

I also attempted to add the additional parameters "/v" and "/qn" which return an error : *Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/v'*

The bottom attempt runs but it's not waiting for the installation to complete

Comment: why are you NOT including the other parameters of the setup.exe you show in the 1st example? i suspect you need the `/qn` to make things do a quiet install ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I attempted to use /v and /qn which promptly returned an error - Like this : Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/v'

Comment: you need to read up on how to use `Start-Process` ... especially on how to pass arguments to it. DO NOT just throw text at it. [*grin*] instead, use the full parameter names followed by the values for each parameter. you will [at least] get more to-the-point error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  You need to quote the whole argumentlist, plus embed double quotes to pass what you want to /v.

```
start-process -wait SetupStata16.exe -ArgumentList '/s /v"/qb ADDLOCAL=core,StataMP64"'
```

Running the command normally and then using wait-process after might be a simpler alternative, if you're sure there's only one process with that name:

```
notepad
wait-process notepad
```

Comment: this worked - if I used the argument list in a fully quoted string it performed the task just as intended

Answer (score 2):

You may be overthinking it. Remember that PowerShell is a *shell*. One of the purposes of a shell is to run commands that you type.

Thus: You don't need `Start-Process`. Just type the command to run and press `Enter`.

```
PS C:\> .\setup.exe /clone_wait /S /v /qn
```

Now if the executable (or script) you want to run contains spaces in the path or name, then use the call/invocation operator (`&`) and specify the quotes; for example:

```
PS C:\> & "\package files\setup.exe" /clone_wait /S /v /qn
```

(This behavior is the same no matter whether you are at the PowerShell prompt or if you put the command in a script.)

Comment: I tried the above in powershell as an admin - the command doesn't create an error but the application doesn't install or open the install wizard

Comment: The command I posted presumes that the command-line arguments in the examples are correct (which I took from your question). Of course, if the arguments are _not_ correct, the command won't work, but that has nothing to do with PowerShell.

Comment: The only issue was the ' " characters - your statement is entirely true, the only problem I had was not wrapping my parameters.

Comment: Right - `Start-Process` is not necessary in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

To follow-up to all that you have been given thus far. Running executables via PowerShell is a well-documented use case.

- [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
- [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
- [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
- [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their
  weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)

So, from the first link provides more validation of what you've been given.

```
5. The Call Operator &

Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing with spaces.

In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another command that starts with a number, you have to use the command invocation operator &.

The PowerShell V3.0 parser do it now smarter, in this case you don’t need the & anymore.

Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command parameters

Example:

& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!

With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not always clear! 

In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'
 
& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
 
# or same like that:
 
$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
 
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
 

 

6. cmd /c - Using the old cmd shell
** This method should no longer be used with V3

Why: Bypasses PowerShell and runs the command from a cmd shell. Often times used with a DIR which runs faster in the cmd shell than in PowerShell (NOTE: This was an issue with PowerShell v2 and its use of .Net 2.0, this is not an issue with V3).

Details: Opens a CMD prompt from within powershell and then executes the command and returns the text of that command. The /c tells CMD that it should terminate after the command has completed. There is little to no reason to use this with V3.

Example:

#runs DIR from a cmd shell, DIR in PowerShell is an alias to GCI. This will return the directory listing as a string but returns much faster than a GCI
cmd /c dir c:\windows




7. Start-Process  (start/saps)


Why: Starts a process and returns the .Net process object Jump if -PassThru is provided. It also allows you to control the environment in which the process is started (user profile, output redirection etc). You can also use the Verb parameter (right click on a file, that list of actions) so that you can, for example, play a wav file.

Details: Executes a program returning the process object of the application. Allows you to control the action on a file (verb mentioned above) and control the environment in which the app is run. You also have the ability to wait on the process to end. You can also subscribe to the processes Exited event.

Example:
 
#starts a process, waits for it to finish and then checks the exit code.
$p = Start-Process ping -ArgumentList "invalidhost" -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$p.HasExited
$p.ExitCode


#to find available Verbs use the following code.
$startExe = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -args PowerShell.exe
$startExe.verbs
```